# Google C2DM IPs or subnets

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I need to configure my firewall settings for C2DM.

Which means I need access to

https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin

Does anyone know which subnets that are used for this? It's impossible to use URLs in the firewall in this case :(

Comment: are you sure that firewall is the cause? windows reports that https://android.apis.google.com/ has wrong certificate

Comment: I've noticed that too. But the solution works when I run it local. But not on the server where it's supposed to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your firewalls really require an explicit exception for outgoing (!) TCP on port 80? I'd say that prohibits a whole slew of useful Web techniques.

That said, it's not possible to know for sure the IP address or subnet that a high profile public website is running on. There may be DNS-based load balancing, local mirroring (a la Akamai), plain old server migrations. Trying to pin the IP address down and expecting it to stay that way is utterly useless. DNS resolution exists for a reason; Google provides services based on site name, not on IP address. IP address is an implementation detail that you cannot reasonably rely on.

Unless relaxing the firewall is an option, consider accessing Google via a proxy outside of a firewall.